# Migration results in "Sequence contains no elements" error with inheritance

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a series of entities that inherit from a base entity, such as:

```
public class AcademicYear : BaseEntity
{
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

The base entity looks like:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt}")]
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        public int? CreateUserId { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt}")]
        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

        public int? UpdateUserId { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt}")]

        public DateTime? DeleteDate { get; set; }

        public int? DeleteUserId { get; set; }

        public virtual UserDetail? CreateUser { get; set; }
        public virtual UserDetail? UpdateUser { get; set; }
        public virtual UserDetail? DeleteUser { get; set; }
    }
```

My `DbContext` looks like this:

```
public class MigrationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
        public MigrationDbContext(DbContextOptions<MigrationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public MigrationDbContext()
        {
        }
    
        public DbSet<AcademicYear> AcademicYears { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<AcademicYear>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
            builder.Entity<AcademicYear>().Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            builder.Entity<AcademicYear>().HasOne(x => x.CreateUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.CreateUserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
            builder.Entity<AcademicYear>().HasOne(x => x.UpdateUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.UpdateUserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
            builder.Entity<AcademicYear>().HasOne(x => x.DeleteUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.DeleteUserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        }
}
```

When I try and run this with

```
add-migration InitialCreate -context MigrationDbContext
```

I get this error

> Sequence contains no elements

If I comment out the last 3 virtual properties of the base entity and the reference to these in `OnModelCreating`, then the migration runs fine.

What do I need to do to get it to run with those relationships defined in the base entity intact?

Comment: I tried your code, It will not show `Sequence contains no elements` after migration, But after I update-database, It will show `cause cycles or multiple cascade paths`.